# How can I perform actions on a listview.builder recursivly?

Tags: flutter

How can I perform actions on a list recursivly?

i have a question can you plz show me that when we create listview by listview builder in menubar then how to perform actioin by percular text or icon  just like we have list of 
about us,
contact us,
refer and earn
feedback 
how can we call that perticular thing 
in listview.builder??

Answer (score 0):

onPressed() returns the index of listview item,
So by making the decision based on returned index, you can achieve the separate action for each listview.builer items....

```
List<String> items = ['about us', 'contact us', 'refer and earn', 'feedback'];

ListView.builder(
      itemCount: widget.items.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return ListTile(
          title: Text(items[index]),
          trailing: RaisedButton(
            child: Text(items[index]),
            color: Colors.pinkAccent,
            onPressed: () {
              print (index);
              switch(index){
                case 0:
                  Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => aboutUs()));
                  break;
                case 1:
                  Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => contactUs()));
                  break;
                case 2:
                  Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => referAndEarn()));
                  break;
                case 3:
                  Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => feedback()));
              }
            },
          ),
        );
      }
    ),
```

The separate action classes are:

```
class aboutUs extends StatelessWidget {


@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text("About Us Page"),),
      body: Container(),
    );
  }
}

class contactUs extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text("Contact Us Page"),),
      body: Container()
    );
  }
}

class referAndEarn extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text("Refer And Earn Page"),),
      body: Container(),
    );
  }
}

class feedback extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text("Feedback Page"),),
      body: Container(),
    );
  }
}
```